# Identify the app termination through Finite length tasks

Tags: ios, swift, background

In order to identify the app termination, i have implemented the Finite-length task but after some period of time app gets terminated and started from start screen.

```
func registerBackgroundTask() {
    backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask { [weak self] in
        self?.endBackgroundTask()
    }
    assert(backgroundTask != .invalid)
}


func endBackgroundTask() {
    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTask)
    backgroundTask = .invalid
    if backgroundTask != .invalid {
        endBackgroundTask()
    }
}

 func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    registerBackgroundTask()
}
```

app should not be terminated when performing Finite-Length tasks, also please provide examples to identify about the termination of the application when it is in suspended mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> app should not be terminated when performing Finite-Length tasks

That's not promised at all. There are lots of reasons your app might be terminated. `beginBackgroundTask` is a request to the OS for more time to finish executing a short-running operation for the user. It doesn't promise your request will be granted.

The specific way you're doing this is likely to fail occasionally, and is specifically addressed in the docs:

> Call this method as early as possible before starting your task, and preferably before your app actually enters the background. The method requests the task assertion for your app asynchronously. If you call this method shortly before your app is due to be suspended, there is a chance that the system might suspend your app before that task assertion is granted. For example, do not call this method at the end of your applicationDidEnterBackground(_:) method and expect your app to continue running. If the system is unable to grant the task assertion, it calls your expiration handler.

You want to wrap the specific operation you want to request time for. You always wrap that operation, whether you think you're going into the background or not. You don't just call this every time you go into the background.

> please provide examples to identify about the termination of the application when it is in suspended mode.

In `applicationWillEnterBackground` write a value into `UserDefaults`. In `applicationDidEnterForeground`, remove the key. In `applicationWillFinishLaunching`, look for that key. If it's there, then you're being relaunched, so at some point you died in the background. That includes something like a reboot or power-failure. If it's not there, then this is first launch, or you crashed in the foreground. The precise way to implement this highly depends on what you plan to do with the information.